# GeoServer vector tile preview fails to load SourceMap

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Very new to GeoServer and web mapping in general. My end goal is to publish data from PostGIS through GeoServer and OpenLayers. I have PostgreSQL/PostGIS and GeoServer on localhost.

When I try to preview data (either my own or the data that is already available upon installing GeoServer) as cached Mapbox vector tiles (pbf), I get the error:

> DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/web/openlayers3/ol.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I interpret this as that it is supposed to show some sort of base map, but fails? How do I solve this?

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Answer (score 1):

The cause possibly related to your browser settings. Based on this thread [DevTools failed to load Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339968/devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content-for-chrome-extension)

> That's because Chrome added support for source maps.
> Go to the developer tools (F12 in the browser), then select the three dots in the upper right corner, and go to Settings.
> Then, look for Sources, and disable the options: "Enable javascript source maps" "Enable CSS source maps"
> If you do that, that would get rid of the warnings. It has nothing to do with your code. Check the developer tools in other pages and you will see the same warning.

Comment: Thank you! So there´s actually no error? Using Firefox and can´t find those options under "Developer tools". The only JavaScript related option is "Disable JavaScript".